# express.static(__dirname+'/public') is not working

Tags: node.js, express

My app's directory structure:

```
app
  -views
    -index.html
    -article.html
  -public
    -stylesheet.js
```

And my coding:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var hbs = require('hbs');
var blogEngine = require('./blog');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
app.use(express.json(), express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index',{title:"My Blog", entries:blogEngine.getBlogEntries()});
});
app.get('/article/:id', function(req, res) {
    var entry = blogEngine.getBlogEntry(req.params.id);
    res.render('article',{title:entry.title, blog:entry});
});
app.listen(8888);
```

When use `localhost:8888`, the stylesheet.js is loaded nicely. But when I use `localhost:8888/article.html`, the stylesheet does not load.
I followed `{{title}}` works in `article.html` file But when I try to see the code of stylesheet, I see error text:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

Why `entry.title` is `undefined` for stylesheet(except the index page)?

Comment: What does your article.html look like?

Comment: <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{blog.title}}</h1>
Published: {{blog.published}}
{{blog.body}}
</body>
</html>

Comment: Great thanks @mscdex. It is working with `/stylesheet.css`

Answer (score 1):

Change the `href` to `/stylesheet.css`. When you visit `/article/..` the browser looks up `/article/stylesheet.css` because the `href` is (currently) a relative path in your article.html.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem related with the `stylesheet.js` rather with the function call in `var entry = blogEngine.getBlogEntry(req.params.id);`

It apparently is returning `undefined` then when it tries to read `entry.title` it throws that error.

Comment: I linked the stylesheet with index.html and article.html. How can I load the stylesheet.js with article.html?